# Mock axios create in test file. React, typescript

Tags: reactjs, testing, axios, jestjs, mocking

I've seen some similar posts about mocking axios but I have spend some hours and I didn't manage to solve my problem and make my test work. I've tried solutions that I have found but they didn't work.

I'm writing small app using React, Typescript, react-query, axios. I write tests with React Testing Library, Jest, Mock Service Worker.
To test delete element functionality I wanted just to mock axios delete function and check if it was called with correct parameter.
Here is the PROBLEM:
I'm using axios instance:

```
//api.ts
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_AIRTABLE_API_KEY}`,
  },
```

```
//api.ts
export const deleteRecipe = async (
  recipeId: string
): Promise<ApiDeleteRecipeReturnValue> => {
  try {
    const res = await axiosInstance.delete(`/recipes/${recipeId}`);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
};
});
```

```
//RecipeItem.test.tsx 
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  const mockAxios = jest.createMockFromModule<AxiosInstance>('axios');
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('axios'),
    create: jest.fn(() => mockAxios),
    delete: jest.fn(),
  };
});

test('delete card after clicking delete button ', async () => {
  jest
    .spyOn(axios, 'delete')
    .mockImplementation(
      jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({ data: { deleted: 'true', id: `${recipeData.id}` } })
      )
    );

  render(
    <WrappedRecipeItem recipe={recipeData.fields} recipeId={recipeData.id} />
  );
  const deleteBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /delete/i });
  user.click(deleteBtn);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(axios.delete).toBeCalledWith(getUrl(`/recipes/${recipeData.id}`));
  });
});
```

In test I get error "Error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

However if I would not use axios instance and have code like below, the test would work.

```
//api.ts
const res = await axios.delete(`/recipes/${recipeId}`);
```

I'm pretty lost and stuck. I've tried a lot of things and some answers on similar problem that I've found on stackoverflow, but they didn't work for me. Anybody can help?
I don't want to mock axios module in **mocks**, only in specific test file.
I don't have also experience in Typescript and testing. This project I'm writing is to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some workaround and at least it's working. I moved axiosInstance declaration to a separate module and then I mocked this module and delete function.

```
//RecipeItem.test.tsx
jest.mock('axiosInstance', () => ({
  delete: jest.fn(),
}));

test('delete card after clicking delete button and user confirmation', async () => {
  jest
    .spyOn(axiosInstance, 'delete')
    .mockImplementation(
      jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({ data: { deleted: 'true', id: `${recipeData.id}` } })
      )
    );
  render(
    <WrappedRecipeItem recipe={recipeData.fields} recipeId={recipeData.id} />
  );
  const deleteBtn = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /delete/i });
  user.click(deleteBtn);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(axiosInstance.delete).toBeCalledWith(`/recipes/${recipeData.id}`);
  });
});
```

If you have a better solution I would like to see it.

Comment: a minor observation: you don't need to provide mockImplementation for axiosInstance.delete if all you are going to do is expect(axiosInstance.delete).toBeCalledWith(...)